# On changing of screen size stop youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, screen

I have design & develop a page with iframe youtube video like below

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WATCH-ID-1?rel=0"  class="hidden-xs"></iframe>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WATCH-ID-2?rel=0"  class="visible-xs"></iframe>
```

My issue is that - when i play first video in Desktop and resize window to mobile screen i need to stop first video playing..

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're effectively changing the website by going from desktop mode to mobile mode, of course it's going to stop playing. At least that's what I think you meant, I can't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Hello Green Swirly,

Thanks for your reply.

I meant to say i have two different videos in one page,  1 for desktop & 2nd for mobile..

When i play the desktop video and change the resolution to mobile the desktop video should stop or pause automatically

Comment: why are you attempting to turn it into mobile? why don't you just run both videos on opposite sides of the screen (one video on the left, the other on the right)? It would be easier and wouldn't cause this issue, and the picture would be larger.

Comment: because i have to hide desktop video in mobile & mobile video in desktop.. its gets hide but playing does not stops..

i tried using window.resize function but no success

Comment: also my client as higher resolution mobile 720 x 1280... which converts mobile site to desktop in landscape orientation

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: thanks Green Swirly.. for your replies... I have resolved the issue using window resize js function and youtube enable js api... 
your help appreciated